# how can I redirect the user to the page he was trying to access after sign-in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i am trying to achieve this:

**case 1 (classic)**: the user logs in ---> is redirected to the homepage.

**case 2**: the user follows a link to an app page ---> is asked to log in ---> after log in is redirected to the page he was trying to access instead of the homepage.

do you have any advice on how / what I could use to do this?

what i did so far:

```
 const loginMutation = useMutation(loginQueries.login.fn, {
    onSuccess: enter,
    onError: showLoginError,
})
function enter() {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries()
    history.push('/')
}
```

Comment: Just before asking the user to login, you may get the url the user was on and transfer it to the login url via querystring. When the user signs in, the auth function an redirect user back to that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch the desired location and store it before redirecting to authentication, then provide the stored location to the `LoginScreen` after the user has authenticated.

I think you can find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70647232/how-to-redirect-a-user-to-any-page-they-try-to-access-after-authentication-cond) useful:

Comment: If questions are duplicates then it's more acceptable to vote or flag as such versus providing an answer that links to the other post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package react-router-dom. You can find extended information in internet.
With it you can write something similar to this:

```html
function App() {
  if (!token) {
    // if no token is defined, than show the login form/component
    return <Login updateToken={callbackToSetToken}></Login>;    
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Application</h1>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={"HOME"}></Route>
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard></Dashboard>}></Route>
            <Route path="reports" element={<Reports></Reports>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```